# Not storing correct persist value

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

Having a problem where after reopening the app the i1-i5 values are all replaced with the user_cur_inv value. Cannot find why this is happening.

Link to the code:
https://github.com/sleedham1991/FantasyTrader/blob/master/src/main.c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These constants are all keys, not values. Make them unique and the problem is solved.

- define PERSIST_USER_GP 1000
- define PERSIST_MAX_INV 10
- define PERSIST_CUR_INV 0
- define PERSIST_I1 0
- define PERSIST_I2 0
- define PERSIST_I3 0
- define PERSIST_I4 0
- define PERSIST_I5 0

See https://developer.pebble.com/docs/c/Foundation/Storage/#persist_write_int